# Setting div style using JQuery/Javascript is being skipped

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure why this is happening. I thought javascript execution was fairly straightforward, but it appears a line of code I have is being skipped.  Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/jbalsamo/pen/OVdOPV) for it.

Basically, when I click a check box I want an invisible `<div>` to become visible then go back to invisible.  Somehow its being skipped.  I added a long loop to make sure it wasn't just disappearing super fast without a flash but.. i don't know.

```js
function change_state(chx) {
  alert('in');
  if (chx.checked) {
    alert('hey its checked');
    $('#divWait').css('display', 'table'); // this <div> never shows up
    DoStuff();
    $('#divWait').css('display', 'none');
  } else {
    alert('not checked');
  }
}

function DoStuff() {
  var x = 0
  while (x < 1000000) {
    x = x + 1;
  }
  alert(x);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="color: white;">
  Change Div State
  <input onchange="change_state(this)" type="checkbox" value="something" id="btnState" />
</div>

<div id="divWait" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; background-color: blue; color: yellow; display: none;">
  What the eff???
</div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What is `change_state()`? Also the Codepen logic is entirely different to whats in the question. Please put all relevant code *in the question*

Comment: Yes. Please show your JavaScript/JQuery code. Thanks.

Comment: it would be good to have a small wait with `setTimeout(function(){$('#divWait').css('display', 'none');}, 200);` to see the effect taking place, having a loop BLOCKS the thread and you see nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NikosM pointed out in his comment, you should use [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to invoke a piece of code after some delay. Using a loop wouldn't help in what you are trying to achieve for 2 reasons:

1. Modern day systems are very fast and any delay introduced by your rather simple loop, will not be noticeable
2. A loop will **block** the execution of your script, making your UI unresponsive, and there is no guarantee that style changes applied right before the loop will get reflected while the control is within the loop

**Solution:**

Wrap the code to hide your `div` within `setTimeout()` and specify the delay in *milliseconds*.

```js
function change_state(chx) {
  console.log('in');
  if (chx.checked) {
    console.log('hey its checked');
    $('#divWait').css('display', 'table'); // this <div> never shows up
    
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('hiding div');
      $('#divWait').css('display', 'none');
    }, 3000); // Specify timeout in milliseconds
  } else {
    console.log('not checked');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="color: white;">
  Change Div State
  <input onchange="change_state(this)" type="checkbox" value="something" id="btnState" />
</div>

<div id="divWait" style="width: 200px; height: 50px; background-color: blue; color: yellow; display: none;">
  What the eff???
</div>
```

Notice that I have replaced `alert()` with `console.log()` to remove annoying alert boxes.